# NullPointer Exception In running testCases via Selenium webDriver in Chrome

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run my test cases on Chrome and I had copied the path in the Properties file,but still console is throwing annoying statements like:
ERROR: The path to the chromedriver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromium/downloads/list
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest startWebSession
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I have found is that the Chrome driver cannot be started from within Eclipse.  It must be run from a command prompt.  At least on Windows 7 *64-bit*.

Trying to run it from within Eclipse produces this exception:

> Exception in thread "*main*" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The webdriver.chrome.driver system property defined chromedriver executable does not exist: C:\Windows\System32\chromedriver.exe

This problem only occurs for Chrome.  IE and FireFox work fine from within Eclipse.

Comment: This might be the OS problem , I will update after trying the same.

Answer (score 2):

Download the chrome driver from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Initialize your driver object in the following manner -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

By doing this the chrome driver works properly.

Comment: There are two ways to do this :
 one is the setProperty thing which is system based , which can be set by giving relativePath (Selenium provide it) like this for IEdriver and same will happen for chrome:
          `code`  File file = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\tools\\iedriver_32\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.
              getAbsolutePath());
            WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

`code`
Now another thing user can start thre driver from command prompt which Mike mentioned above .

Answer (score 0):

This is how do I initialize the ChromeDriver:

```
public RegulationUI() throws Exception{
   ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
   File file = new File(RegulationUI.class.getResource("/chromedriver.exe").toURI());
   System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, file.getAbsolutePath());                
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
   driver = new ChromeDriver(service,options);
}
```

BTW my test class is named `RegulationUI`

Try this, it works for me and moreover, I know that this is "multicomputer" solution - our project is in subversion and this way everybody can run it, even if we have differently setup where exactly on disk the "working folder" for IDE is

Comment: Hey Pavel ,I tried with:<pre><code>if (BrowserType.toLowerCase().equals("chrome")) {
     DesiredCapabilities chromecapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
     chromecapabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "C:/workspaceNewSFDC/HI_SalesForce");
     ChromeDriverService    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
             .usingChromeDriverExecutable(new File("C:/workspaceNewSFDC/HI_SalesForce/chromedriver.exe"))
             .usingAnyFreePort()
             .build();
         service.start();
     driver = new ChromeDriver(service);
    }
   }

Comment: I have Java for this and am not good programmer, but:
I believe the path should always contain also "chromedriver.exe" in it

Comment: I had already pasted the path of ChromeDriver.exe in my properties file.But every-time I run my Test-cases Console is throwing the same error!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please download chromedriver.exe for Google chrome browser 
    please download IEdriver.exe for Internet explore.
```

Please And kept these files in a root folder of windows for simplicity. Lets consider your operating systems installed on c:\ (C Driver) create a folder name Selenium on C-Drive and Kept these binary(.exe) files. like c:\selenium

```
    in your Testcase/testScript Write as 

    //For Chrome Browser:
    Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    java.io.File file = new File("c:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");     
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven then try to use following in your pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and use it like this for chrome in your setup:

```
    ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: I have the same problem,  getting a null.PointerException when I try to run Chrome in my IntelliJ IDE. I can run IE11 OK but not Chrome. I tried all of these suggestions in this thread but did not solve my problem.

Here is how I'm currently configuring Chrome:

ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary(RunConfiguration.getBrowserPath());
chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", RunConfiguration.getBrowserDriverPath());
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);}